# Filtering an array list by age?

Tags: java

I need to filter a list of customer info and print our a list of people over the age of 65.

I created a method first that looks like this...

```
public static boolean eligibleForRetirement(int age) {
        if (age >= 65) { 
            return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

and another method that prints out the list

```
public static void menuOptionThree(){
        ArrayList<Customer> list = generateFromFile("Week3ProgrammingDataUpdate.csv");
        ArrayList<Customer> customersOver65 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            Customer.eligibleForRetirement(0).add(customersOver65);
            System.out.println(customersOver65);
        }
```

but this is not working. I am getting an error that says "Cannot invoke add(ArrayList) on the primitive type boolean."

Comment: How is it supposed to work if it doesn't even compile...did You try to get rid of compilation errors ?

Comment: Please edit your *first* question, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: I dont think this code would even compile, since the method eligibleForRetirement() returns an boolean and you call a add()-Function on it. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @endriu_l: That is his compilation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the mininum change in you code, would be like this:

```
public static boolean eligibleForRetirement(Customer c) {
        if (c.getAge() >= 65) { 
            return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
```

//

```
ArrayList<Customer> list = generateFromFile("Week3ProgrammingDataUpdate.csv");
     ArrayList<Customer> customersOver65 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    for(Custumer customer: list ){
        if (Customer.eligibleForRetirement(customer)){
        customersOver65.add(customer);

    }
    System.out.println(customersOver65);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding to either of the ArrayLists. In fact, your code is trying to add an ArrayList to a method in your Customers class.